# Slow for loop in R

Tags: r, performance, loops

I'm trying to extract data from several files in NCDef (.nc) format. The code I wrote works, but slowly, and I'd appreciate any suggestions!

My working code pulls a file, called `temp`, using RNetCDF and converts it into a "long list" in which each variable has either one or three dimensions (lat, lon, and pft). I then pull the data from each of my variables one at a time (`varlist[j]`) and convert it into a dataframe. Adply then breaks this out by each of the three dimensions. The last step, creating `files`, allows me to use cbind and rbind to put all the files together into one large dataframe.

The code is as follows:

```
setwd("C:/Users/User/Box Sync/_PhD/PhD_Research/Albedo/Data_CLM/PFTRuns/2005/")
fname<-"b40.20th.1deg.bdrd.002bc.clm2.h0.2005-"
numlist<-c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
varlist<-c(1,2,4,8,9,21)
varname<-c("lon","lat","pft","pft_wtgcell","pft_wtcol","FSR")
files<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=12, ncol=length(varlist))

`for (i in 12:12) {
  temp<- paste(c(fname, numlist[i],'.nc'), collapse='')
  temp<-read.nc(open.nc(temp))
  temp<-structure(temp, row.names = c(NA, -288), class = "data.frame")
  for (j in 3:length(varlist)) {
    newname<-paste(c("Y2005", numlist[i],".", varname[j]), collapse='')
    if (j<4){
        assign(newname, adply(temp[,varlist[j]], c(1)))}
    else{
        assign(newname, adply(temp[,varlist[j]], c(1,2,3)))}
    files[i,j]<-newname}}`
```

*EDIT* 
Here is an example of the read.nc(open.nc()) output. 
[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0qnb.png)

Comment: You may want to post more of your code if you are looking for process improvements.  Posting a sample of the output of `read.nc(open.nc(temp)` would help.  There could be performance improvement in avoiding the multiple conversions to a dataframe and performing that operation at the end.  Also moving from the plyr package to dplyr could be another performance boost.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, I have added that output, as well as showing more of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over your problem.  You have a series of 3d arrays which you would like to flatten to a 1d array and align with the coordinates vectors (lon, lat and put).
While the package plyr has many very useful functions, they have a tendency to be slow.  As in your case above.

Here the sample data which I created for testing:

```
#create some test data
set.seed(1)
lon<-1:300
lat<-1:200
pft<-1:15
tot<-length(lon)*length(lat)*length(pft)
pft_wtgcell<- array(rnorm(tot, 10), dim=c(length(lon),length(lat),length(pft)))
pft_wtcol<- array(rnorm(tot, 60, 2), dim=c(length(lon),length(lat),length(pft)))
FSR<- array(rnorm(tot, 100, 3), dim=c(length(lon),length(lat),length(pft)))
temp<-list(lon=lon, lat=lat, pft=pft, pft_wtgcell=pft_wtgcell, pft_wtcol=pft_wtcol, FSR=FSR)
```

Here is my solution:

```
numlist<-c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
#varlist<-c(1,2,4,8,9,21)
varname<-c("lon","lat","pft","pft_wtgcell","pft_wtcol","FSR")
files<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=12, ncol=length(varname))
#loop to cycle through the file starts here:
i<-1

#crate data.frame for lon, lat and pft
newname<-paste(c("Y2005", numlist[i],".", varname[1]), collapse='')
coord<-expand.grid(temp$lon, temp$lat, temp$pft)
assign(newname, coord)
files[i,1]<-newname
#loop through the variables of interest
#  could probly be simplified.
for (j in 4:length(varname)) {
  newname<-paste(c("Y2005", numlist[i],".", varname[j]), collapse='')
  assign(newname, as.data.frame.table(temp[[varname[j] ]])$Freq)
  files[i,j]<-newname
}
```

I have avoided conversion of the sample data into a data frame and decide to work directly on the list.  The `expand.grid` function quickly creates a data frame of all of the possible combinations of lon, lat and pft.  Searching for hints on how to flatten a 3d array, I found references to `as.data.frame.table` function which works in this case, also I am just storing the last (flatten) column of data.  With only the needed data being stored in the data.frame, the rbinds should also perform faster.

I have not performed extensive checking for errors, but on my laptop, I saw a 500x improvement in speed for the above test case.

If this works for you please accept the answer, if not I can tweak some more.

Comment: Surely this problem can be solved without using `assign`.

Comment: Yes, I would have preferred not using the assign statement, but since the original code used it to create resultant "files" matrix, I left it in.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I can't quite use it as is, because I need to be able to read lat, lon, and pft from the ncdef file as well, but I may be able to read them first and then use them to create "coord" as you showed above.

Comment: Adjusted it to use your suggestions, see below. This runs very quickly now, thank you!

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  It should be: expand.grid(temp$lon, temp$lat, temp$pft).  I fixed the code above to reflect the correction.  This is what happens without the actual data.  I am glad you were able to figure out the correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I settled on, with the help of @Dave2e

```
#Library Settings #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(RNetCDF);library(data.table);library(plyr); library(arrayhelpers)
#File Settings #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setwd("C:/Users/User/Box Sync/_PhD/PhD_Research/Albedo/Data_CLM/PFTRuns/2005/")
fname<-"b40.20th.1deg.bdrd.002bc.clm2.h0.2005-"
numlist<-c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
varlist<-c(1,2,4,8,9,21)
varname<-c("lon","lat","pft","pft_wtgcell","pft_wtcol","FSR")
files<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=12)

for (i in 1:12) {
  temp<- paste(c(fname, numlist[i],'.nc'), collapse='')
  temp<-read.nc(open.nc(temp))
  for (j in 1:3){
    vars<-temp[[varlist[j]]]
    newname<-paste(c("Y2005",".", varname[j]), collapse='')
    assign(newname, vars)}
  coord<-expand.grid(Y2005.lon, Y2005.lat, Y2005.pft)
  coord$month<-c(numlist[i])
  newname<-paste(c("Y2005", numlist[i]), collapse=''); assign(newname, coord)
  for (j in 4:length(varlist)){
    temp2<-array2df(temp[[varlist[j]]], label.x=varname[j])
    assign(newname, cbind(temp2, get(newname)))}
  files[i]<-newname}
Y2005<-lapply(files, cbind)
```